# sql & php associative array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I'm building a website and I need an array of 'related posts', the array $previews. This array needs to contain three arrays, each of them with data from a related post. I tried getting the data using this code, but it fails:

```
$previews = array();

$query = mysql_query("SELECT TOP 3 title, url, category, date_published FROM post WHERE NOT(id = '$my_id') AND category = '$my_category' ORDER BY NEWID()");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) $previews[] = $row;
```

I keep getting "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given".

Can somebody please help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you Google the error message?

Comment: This has probably asked a 100 times before. And the answer is always: do not use msql*, do error checks and find out that `$query` is not a resource but a boolean due to a error in the query string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it may work.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT TOP 3 title, url, category, date_published FROM post WHERE NOT(id = '".$my_id."') AND category = '".$my_category."' ORDER BY NEWID()");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) $previews[] = $row;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query fails to return any values due to error or permission access issues, $query will be be the boolean false.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know a query could return false in that way.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because something with your query went wrong. Try to call `die(var_dump(mysql_error($query)));` to see what went wrong.

Comment: It says NULL. Does this mean my database contains no matches or..?

Comment: It says that no catchable error message was found. In fact your SQL looks a bit strange and I wonder why there is no error.
Did you call mysql_connect and mysql_select_db before the mysql_query?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is wrong. It looks like MsSQL not MySQL. I'm not sure about the whole thing, but TOP 3 should be removed and you should use limit at the end of the query.

**Was:**

```
    SELECT TOP 3 title, url, category, date_published FROM post WHERE NOT(id = '$my_id') AND category = '$my_category' ORDER BY NEWID()
```

**Should be:**

```
    SELECT title, url, category, date_published FROM post WHERE id != '$my_id' AND category = '$my_category' ORDER BY NEWID limit 3
```

Comment: is NEWID a field? If so, remove the () from the end of it in the order clause.

Comment: I updated my query string to what I'd think it should be, but no one here knows your db schema so you might want to look into ready some mysql docs or building your query with phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

It works with:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT title, url, category, date_published FROM post WHERE NOT(id = '$my_id') AND category = '$my_category' limit 3");
```

So the problem must be the ORDER BY NEWID().

Thanks for your comments everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would check to see if the query was successful before operating on the result object:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT fields FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result)
{
    // operate on results i.e. fetching assoc etc.
}
else
{
    // handle error accordingly
    // use mysql_error() for debugging or maybe logging
}

?>
```

`mysql_query()` returns `false` if the query was unsuccessful.

Also, as a few others have mentioned, your SQL syntax is incorrect and looks like TSQL/MSSQL.